# Determine continuity of function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{\pi}{2}+arcsin \left(\frac {3x}{2x+1}\right)  & x\in[-\frac{1}{5},1] \\
\\
\sqrt{|5x+1|}\ &  x\in R-[-\frac{1}{5},1]\\
\end{cases}
$$

[image]

Are the calculations correct?

Comment: Your use of $\lim$ notation is not correct. Notice in your first point that you take the limit as $x$ tends to something of an expression that does not contain any $x$. For the second point, just write $\lim_{x \to -\frac{1}{5}} \sqrt{|5x+1|} = \lim_{x \to 0} \sqrt{x} = 0$. Your reasoning is correct but your have notation issues.

Answer (score 1):

Both functions used in the definition are continuous on the specified domains so we must check for continuity where they "meet" at $-\tfrac{1}{5}$ and $1$.

You have done this mostly correctly at $x=-\tfrac{1}{5}$ (with the exception of leaving limit symbols in your work after you have already taken the limit). But at $x=1$ we find that

\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to1^+}f(x)=\sqrt{6}
\end{equation}

whereas $f(1)=\tfrac{\pi}{2}+\arcsin(1)=\pi\ne\sqrt{6}$

so the function is continuous at $-\tfrac{1}{5}$ but not at $1$.

Note that this problem is trickier than it looks because $\arcsin\left(\dfrac{3x}{2x+1}\right)$ is undefined outside the closed interval given.

Answer (score 0):

Determine where your two functions are discontinuous along their given domain. For example, where does $ arcsin(\frac{3x}{2x+1}) $ become undefined. Clearly this is wherever the denominator would be equal to zero, which never happens along this domain. Inspect the second function along this domain and you'll similarly find that there are no points of discontinuity. Therefore your function is continuous along its domain.

EDIT
Also you need to find the limit from approaching x=1 from the right and left to complete this. Then check the points along the domain.

Comment: Yes, it needs to check $x=1$ as well where the function is not continuous.